# Why the available parities of the infinite well solutions change as we change the boundaries positions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

So, I have noticed something in the solutions of the infinite quantum well and I don't quite understand it. The solutions are of the form

\begin{equation}
\phi_{n}(x) = A\cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)
\end{equation}

If the boundaries of the well are at $x=0$ and $x=L$ then the boundary condition $\phi_{n}(x=0)=0$ leads to $A=0$, meaning that we only have odd-parity solutions available.

If, however, the boundaries of the well are at $x=-a$ and $x=a$ we have

\begin{eqnarray}
A\cos(ka)+B\sin(ka)=0 \\
A\cos(ka)-B\sin(ka)=0 
\end{eqnarray}

which leads us too

\begin{eqnarray}
A\cos(ka)=0 \\
B\sin(ka)=0 
\end{eqnarray}

giving rise to odd and even parity solutions.

How come we gain one type of solutions by moving the boundary? Shouldn't the system be the same independently of where we decide to put the origin of our system?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *energies* will be the same but the solutions - of course - will not.  The simplest example is to compare $\cos(x)$ which is even, with $\sin(x)$, which is odd.  If you just translate by $\pi/2$, then $\cos(x-\pi/2)=\sin(x)$: by simply translating the origin you change the parity of the function.  Of course, a sine function is just a cosine function shifted by $\pi/2$ so displacing (or shifting) the original does not affect the *shape* of the solution although it does affect its parity.

The parity depends quite fundamentally where you place your origin, since parity is a reflection about a reference points: if your well extends from $0$ to $2a$, it is *not* symmetric but if it extends from $-a$ to $a$, then it certainly is symmetric.

In fact, it is entirely possible to solve this problem with the well from $0$ to $2a$ without using parity arguments.  The parity operation allows you to connect the boundary conditions, thus dividing the work by $2$, but the cost is that you must solve for the even and odd solutions separately, so there is no real savings in terms of work, although there is additional insight into the solutions.